# AutoHotkey - use dictionary/lookup to make hotstring replacements

Tags: dictionary, autohotkey

I am trying to write an AutoHotkey script to give an easy way to input modified Latin characters (e.g. ö, å, é, ñ, etc). Let's say I want to send the combination `(vowel)` + `;` + `\` to `(vowel)` with an umlaut on it. I could do something like

```
:?*:a;\::ä
:?*:e;\::ë
:?*:i;\::ï
:?*:o;\::ö
:?*:u;\::ü
```

However, I was wondering if there was a more "slick" or "abstract" way to do it, where I could define a set of mappings beforehand, e.g.

```
Umlaut = {  a -> ä,  e -> ë,  i -> ï,  o -> ö,  u -> ü  }
```

and then apply the pattern to all elements of this mapping, e.g.

```
forall x in Umlaut
  :?*:(x.key);\::(x.value)
```

**Is such a thing possible in AutoHotkey?**

If yes, I'm wondering **if it's also possible to take the abstraction one level further.** E.g. suppose I also wanted to send the combination `(vowel)` + `'` + `\` to `(vowel)` with an acute on it. Then, I'd want to define a mapping such as

```
Diacritics = {
  ";" ->  {  a -> ä,  e -> ë,  i -> ï,  o -> ö,  u -> ü  },
  "'" ->  {  a -> á,  e -> é,  i -> í,  o -> ó,  u -> ú  },
}
```

and apply the same pattern

```
forall x in Diacritics
  forall y in x.value
    :?*:(y.key)(x.key);\::(y.value)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, this is very doable with the `Hotstring()`<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Hotstring.htm)</sup> function and a [for-loop](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/For.htm).

```
diacritics := { "a" : "ä"
              , "e" : "ë"
              , "i" : "ï"
              , "o" : "ö"
              , "u" : "ü" }

for key, value in diacritics
    Hotstring(":?*:" key ";\", value)
```

---

Also I wasn't really sure what you meant with your second part of the question, but I'm assuming you mean like
<kbd>a</kbd> + <kbd>;</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd> produces <kbd>ä</kbd>
and
<kbd>a</kbd> + <kbd>'</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd> produces <kbd>á</kbd>,
then this code would work:

```
diacritics := { ";" : { "a" : "ä"
                      , "e" : "ë"
                      , "i" : "ï"
                      , "o" : "ö"
                      , "u" : "ü" }
              , "'" : { "a" : "á"
                      , "e" : "é"
                      , "i" : "í"
                      , "o" : "ó"
                      , "u" : "ú" } }


for outer_key, value1 in diacritics
    for inner_key, value2 in value1
        Hotstring(":?*:" inner_key outer_key "\", value2)
```

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Just to clarify.. In the first example your map variable name is `umlaut`. That should be named `diacritics` right? :-)

Comment: that was a typo, sure. thanks